Get all used methods in a project from an external *.dll
I need to analyze the usage of a specific library across 29 C# projects. This library is included via a *.dll file. The analysis should identify which methods from the library are used in each project.
Ideally, the analysis would be fully automatic and conducted without altering the code within the projects, although solutions that involve automated code modification will be considered.
Attempts So Far:

Parsing all methods in the library and then searching for them in each project.
Problem: there are methods in the projects with identical names as the ones in library, but aren't from the library.

Remove all library usings from the projects and observe errors that are given via MSBuild.exe. Problem: output of the MSBuild.exe does not contain IntelliSense output which would indicate that the method is coming from an external *.dll. E.g.,



Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



Remove library *.dll from the projects and try the same idea as in number 2. Same problem.

Is there a way to automatically append the full namespace to each method in the projects such that it results in "Library.Sublibrary.Class.MethodName"? Alternatively, are there other strategies?

You should probably inspect the actual IL code in the dlls, possibly using something like ILSpy. The call instructions should contain specify the assembly, so it should be fairly straight forward to find the ones pointing at your library.

Jetbrains Resharper extension can do that. There is Code Usage feature, which gives you all occurences where you use the library in some way. You can then iterate over all occurences and see where that method is used. I  believe you can also filter them out.

All referenced methods are stored in the metadata of the assembly file, you can use MetadataReader to extract these information, here is an basic example,
var per = new PEReader(File.OpenRead("ASSEMBLY-FILE-TO-ANALYZE"));
var mr = per.GetMetadataReader();
foreach (var mrefh in mr.MemberReferences)
{
    var mref = mr.GetMemberReference(mrefh);
    if(mref.GetKind() == MemberReferenceKind.Method)
    {
        //the member name
        Console.Write("Method:" + mr.GetString(mref.Name));

        //the parent is a type
        if(mref.Parent.Kind == HandleKind.TypeReference)
        {
            var tref = mr.GetTypeReference((TypeReferenceHandle)mref.Parent);
            //the type name and its namespace
            Console.Write(", Type:" + mr.GetString(tref.Name));
            Console.Write(", Namespace:" + mr.GetString(tref.Namespace));

            //the type is owned by an assembly
            if (tref.ResolutionScope.Kind == HandleKind.AssemblyReference)
            {
                var aref = mr.GetAssemblyReference((AssemblyReferenceHandle)tref.ResolutionScope);
                //the assembly name
                Console.Write(", Assembly:" + mr.GetString(aref.Name));
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


You may need to use Visual Studio extensions.
Such as the answer from similar thread:
How to find which method is from which namespace in Visual Studio

ReSharper：right-click and "Find Usages". This will show all usages of methods,
classes etc in the namespace, as you require. Make sure the cursor is
on "using"


Thank you for your answer, but it still involves a lot of manual work for 29 projects.
